# Substitution matrix for the Ammann-Beenker tiling

Tags: substitution, tiling, tessellations

On the [wikipedia page for the Ammann-Beenker tiling](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ammann%E2%80%93Beenker_tiling#cite_note-7), it says the following:

[image]

I am trying to derive the substitution matrix for and show that its eigenvalues are $(1\pm\sqrt{2})^1$... so far the things I found online all scale as $(1\pm\sqrt{2})^2$.

Where would I start?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The matrix of the 1D silver-mean substitution $R \to RrR, r \mapsto R$ is

$$
\begin{bmatrix}
2 & 1\\
1 & 0
\end{bmatrix}
$$

whose eigenvalues are the silver mean and its PV conjugate $1 \pm \sqrt{2}$.

For the Amman-Beenker substitution, the substitution matrix on the tiles is

$$
\begin{bmatrix}
3 & 2\\
4 & 3
\end{bmatrix}
$$
(where I've chosen to cut the squares into two triangles in order to have a proper Stone inflation - you could also treat these triangles separately if you really wanted, but it doesn't change the calculation as they have the same area and substitute dually)

whose eigenvalues are $(1+\sqrt{2})^2$ and its algebraic conjugate. This makes sense as the Perron-Frobenius eigenvalue of the substitution matrix corresponds to the inflation factor as it acts on **area** so it inflates a region of the plane with area $A$ to a region with area $A(1+\sqrt{2})^2$. Accordingly, as the substitution only expands, and there is no shearing, the linear expansion factor for lengths is just the square root of the area expansion factor, hence $1+\sqrt{2}$.

Comment: Ah of course, the tiling will scale like the area. Thanks!

Comment: FYI you had a typo in the sub matrix for 1D, I fixed it.

Comment: Thanks for fixing the typo.