# Projecting a selection of points from a regular 2D grid onto a line

Tags: projection, projection-matrices

I would like to:

- start with a regular 2D grid like shown in the picture
- chose a line of slope $\tan \alpha$, and project, and a window of acceptance (grey area)
- project the points of the grid within this window onto the line.
- **Find the spacing between the projected points on the line**

This last point is really my end goal. The thing that I would like to prove is that, if $\tan \alpha$ is rational, then the points on the line will form a periodic structure.

[image]

My attempt so far:

From [a previous question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3154850/substitution-matrix-for-the-ammann-beenker-tiling/3155198#3155198), I now know how to project $i$ points onto a line with unit vector $v$:

$$ [p_{p1} \ \ p_{p2} \   \  \dots \ \ p_{pn}]=vv^T[p_1  \ \ p_2 \ \  \dots   \ \ p_n] $$

How can I include in this expression the projection window?
I.e. that as I change $\alpha$, more points will fall within the grey area and hence will be projected?
 
 (I can do it numerically, e.g. the picture above done in `Mathematica`, but I am trying to derive it mathematically and more generally)

Comment: I think that you need also a number theory for solution of this question..

Comment: Square of distance between two projected points is $\Vert d \Vert ^2= (vv^T(p_2-p_1))^T(vv^T(p_2-p_1))= (p_2-p_1)^Tvv^T(p_2-p_1)$

Comment: Yeah thanks, but as I change the angle $\alpha$ there are more points in my window of acceptance...